# Нужны ли кавычки для названий?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Нужны ли кавычки в предложении: Приборы для определения числа падения: 
(")Хагберг – Пертена("), «Falling Number», ПЧП, «Амилотест»

Answer (score 1):

"В русском письме сложилась устойчивая традиция не заключать в кавычки написанные латиницей собственные наименования. При этом отсутствие кавычек определяется именно латиницей, оно, как правило, не зависит ни от количества слов в названии, ни от наличия или отсутствия при названии родового слова." (из http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/77-kav4)